# View a javascript blob in ie11 windows phone 8.1

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8.1, internet-explorer-11

ie11 does not support blob data url's in general. It does support a blob url of an image when set as the src of an image element.

Trying to set a src of an iframe to the blob url (for example an image or pdf file) does not work in ie11

ie11 supports a javascript method msSaveOrOpenBlob which allows you to treat a local blob as if it was downloaded from a server, so using this method you can at least ask the user whether they want to save the file or open the file (using a suitable application)

However the method msSaveOrOpenBlob in ie11 on windows phone 8.1 does not work. The method exists but simply does not work and gives no exception.

So my question is: I have a local blob (loaded from an IndexedDB database), the blob can be an image, pdf or xdoc for example. How do I allow the user to view the file in windows phone 8.1?

Comment: I am experiencing the exact same problem. Lumia 930, Windows Mobile 8.1

Comment: hello Jon, any luck?